# How do I proceed to load a ga_instance as ".pkl" format in PyGad?

Tags: python, pytorch, genetic-algorithm, genetic

I have been trying to load the PyGad trained instance in another file, in order to make some prediction. But I have been having some problems in the loading process.
After the training phase, I saved the instance like this:

The saving function:

filename = 'GNN_CPTNet' #GNN_CPTNet.pkl

ga_instance.save(filename=filename)

The loading function:

loaded_ga_instance = pygad.load(filename=filename)

loaded_ga_instance.plot_result()

But, when I tried to load the instance in a new notebook or script, I could not load the instance, especially the "GNN_CPT Net.pkl" file.

Answer (score 1):

##### Edit on February 28, 2023

###### Starting from `PyGAD 2.19`, the library [cloudpickle](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle) is used instead of `pickle`. Now, you do not have to re-define the functions. So, it is enough to call the `load()` function.

In the new script, you should define the the fitness function and all the callback functions you used in the original script.

For example, if you used only the `on_generation` (`callback_generation`) parameter, then the following functions should be defined:

```py
def fitness_func(solution, solution_idx):
    ...


def callback_generation(ga_instance):
    ...
```

This way, the saved instance will be loaded correctly.

Anyway, it is better to post the sample codes you used to give more accurate answer.

Thanks for using [PyGAD](https://pygad.readthedocs.io) :)

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks Ahmed!

Comment: Good luck, Vinicius. Thanks for using PyGAD :)